# Auto-contrast Font Color to Background

Tags: css, fonts, background, contrast, compare-contrast

I have a background of a field. The bottom is green, the top is gray.  There is text on top of the background. Is there a way for the text to "sense" what color the background is and to tint the font in a way to make it contrast?

For example, the the text over the gray sky would become brighter and the text over the green field would become darker, to make it more visible.

I may be reaching pretty far on this one, but any suggestions are appreciated. (Please note, I am not looking for the answer to manually change the font colors.)

Comment: [Methods for Contrasting Text Against Backgrounds](https://css-tricks.com/methods-contrasting-text-backgrounds) By Ana Tudor, 2017

Comment: 2023 status: `color-contrast()` looks like it will eventually provide a robust method for doing this: [Spec](https://w3c.github.io/csswg-drafts/css-color-6/#colorcontrast) |  [More Examples](https://www.lambdatest.com/blog/css-color-contrast/)

Answer (score 36, accepted):

More as an experiment than otherwise:

Set the text with a background inherit, to get the background of the base; then clip it to the text, and then apply some filters to it:

```
.test {
    width: 800x;
    height:220px;
    font-size: 200px;
    background-image: url(bosque.jpg); 
    color: white;
    position: relative;
}

.inner {
    position: relative;
    background-image: inherit;
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
    color: transparent;
    -webkit-filter: invert() sepia();
}
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vals/9qufy/show)

(Only working in webkit)

Check also this ones:

[animated madness](http://jsfiddle.net/vals/9qufy/1/show)

[contrast animation](http://jsfiddle.net/vals/9qufy/2/show)

UPDATE: We have new ways to handle this. See a demo using `mix-blend-mode: difference`

```css
div {
  font-size: 300px;
  color: gray;
  mix-blend-mode: difference;
}
body {
  background-image: url(http://placekitten.com/900/600);
}
```

```html
<div>TEST</div>
```

Comment: Careful! [`mix-blend-mode` isn't well-supported yet.](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-mixblendmode)

Comment: Apr 2020, it's now supported in everything except IE and Opera Mini (though Safari and Safari Mini have partial; no support for `hue`, `saturation`, `color` and `luminosity`).

Comment: but what if the `<div>` itself hosts both the random `background-color` **and** text `color`... `mix-blend-mode` doesn't work (i would expect it to)

Comment: The above doesn't work in Firefox 88. But it does in Chrome 89.